# invalid service definition or service configuration

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a standard Azure build -- one web role, one worker role.  After the latest merge, it has decided that the roles are invalid.  When I double click on the web role or worker role, or when I right click and choose "Properties", I get a grey screen saying "Invalid service definition or service configuration. Please see the Error List for more details".  However, there is nothing at all in the Error List.

I have cross-compared the Settings elements and tried commenting out sections of the `csdef` and `cscfg` files, but nothing seems to bring the roles back to life.  I have wasted half a day on this already.  My question is not so much "What is wrong" -- more like, how on Earth are you supposed to find out what the error is when no information is given and successive blanking out of code draws a comprehensive blank?

Comment: What happens when you open up csdef/cscfg files? At the very least, they should be valid XML files. Also the `Settings` entries in csdef and cscfg files should match. Can you share the files so that somebody can take a look (obviously removing sensitive information before sharing them)?

Comment: Not long after posting this, I deleted the existing wadcfgx files, and re-generated a new set.  That resolved the problem.  I'll post the solution in more detail when I'm able to answer my own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, nothing was wrong with the `csdef` and `cscfg` files.  It was the way the `wadcfgx` files were linked to the roles.

I'm on a branch that is using Azure 2.5; the other branch is on a previous version of Azure, that uses the older version of diagnostics.  By deleting the existing `wadcfgx` files and re-generating them, I was able to make the roles visible and editable again.  Having different versions on different branches does, of course, open a very large can of worms, but we're stuck with that difficult situation for the time being.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed the `wadcfgx` files that were breaking everything.
I didn't deliberately create them - are they important and is there a trivial way to "regenerate" them without knowing anything about them?

Comment: @Brondahl To regenerate them, right-click the role name in the cloud project and choose the generate diagnostics configuration option.

Comment: @Lukos, not meant to do this, but thanks for explaining how to implement rob lyndons  suggestion

Answer (score 11):

I've run across this a couple of times (VS 2015 Enterprise).  Simply closing and re-opening the solution resolved the issue.

Comment: The funniest thing is that, you have to close-and-reopen the _Solution_. close-and-reopen _Visual Studio_ does not help.

Comment: Sometimes close-and-reopen the solution works for me, sometimes I have to close-and-reopen Visual Studio. Would be nice to find a permanent fix to this.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for sharing. It is really frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

Check if the VM Size specified in the configuration is Small or Extra Small as it doesn't support more than that on local emulator. In my case it was defaulted to Standard Size VM. I changed the size to Extra Small and it started working fine!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this after adding a new Worker Role project to an existing cloud service with a few existing Worker Roles.

In my `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg`, I had a `<NetworkConfiguration>` tag in between the old roles and the new role. This was the problem. I simply moved the `<NetworkConfiguration>` tag to the bottom as it was before (this tag is not in my `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` file, which might've been the problem).

Probably not the most common cause of this problem, but figured I'd post on the off chance someone has similar settings.